# Flow Array Generic is Incompatible with Itself?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm trying to create an es6 class with flow type checking:

```
/* @flow */

export default class ListHolder<Tv> {
  getList = (): Array<Tv> => {
    return [];
  };

  iterateOverList = (): mixed => {
    return this.getList().map((item: mixed, index: number) => {
      // no-op
      return null;
    });
  };
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting a flow error that `Tv [1] is incompatible with Tv [1].` referencing the line `getList = (): Array<Tv> => {`. Can someone help me understand this error?

It resolves if I comment out the `map` invocation, but I haven't been able to make much progress beyond that and the error messages aren't particularly helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your creating a class, but assigning methods to a class is not done using assignment operator.  `=` and arrow functions  `=>`.

I think this is more what your after. ->

```
/* @flow */


export default class ListHolder<Tv> {
  getList (): Array<Tv> {
    return [];
  };

  iterateOverList (): mixed {
    return this.getList().map((item: mixed, index: number) => {
      // no-op
      return null;
    }); 
  };
}
```

Comment: thank you! I thought I was going crazy. So the problem is that because they weren't methods they weren't inheriting the generic, I see what I did wrong. It's weird b/c I feel I've seen the arrow function assignment used elsewhere in JS as a shorthand -- must be my mistake! Thank you again!

Comment: `It's weird b/c I feel I've seen the arrow function assignment used elsewhere in JS as a shorthand`  It is used, but here your defining a class, everything inside the `{}` here is a class definition.  If say you were creating methods inside the constructor you might have seen something like  `this.func = () => {}`.  Here it's not now a class definition but a code execution point were assignments are allowed.

Comment: @Tomas: what you have seen is an experimental feature called *class fields*: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields. It’s a shorthand for defining properties inside the constructor (without having to define the constructor).